# du skip symbolic links

Tags: shell, symlink, wildcards

The default behavior of `du` on my system is not the proper default behavior.

If I `ls` my `/data` folder, I see (removing the stuff that isn't important):

```
ghs
ghsb -> ghs
hope
rssf -> roper
roper
```

Inside each folder is a set of folders with numbers as names. I want to get the total size of all folders named `14`, so I use:

```
du -s /data/*/14
```

And I see...

```
161176 /data/ghs/14
161176 /data/ghsb/14
8 /data/hope/14
681564 /data/rssf/14
681564 /data/roper/14
```

What I want is only:

```
161176 /data/ghs/14
8 /data/hope/14
681564 /data/roper/14
```

I do not want to see the symbolic links.  I've tried `-L`, `-D`, `-S`, etc.  I always get the symbolic links.  Is there a way to remove them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't `du` resolving the symbolic links; it's your shell.

`*` is a shell glob; it is expanded by the shell before running any command. Thus in effect, the command you're running is:

```
du -s /data/ghs/14 /data/ghsb/14 /data/hope/14 /data/rssf/14 /data/roper/14
```

If your shell is bash, you don't have a way to tell it not to expand symlinks. However you can use `find` (GNU version) instead:

```
find /data -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name 14 -exec du -s {} +
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can someone explain the use of `{}` and `+` here?

Comment: [Using semicolon vs plus with exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find)

Answer (score 10):

### Make `du` skip symbolic links:

`du` isn't smart enough to not chase links.  By default `find` will skip symlinks.  So creating an unholy alliance between `find`, `du`, and `awk`, the proper dark magic incantation becomes:

```
find /home/somedirectory/ -exec du -s {} + | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total}'
```

Produces:

> 145070492

To force the output to be human readable:

```
find /home/somedirectory/ -exec du -s {} + | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print (total / 1024 / 1024) "MB"}'
```

Produces:

> 138.35MB

What's going on here:

```
/home/somedirectory/      directory to search.
-exec du -s +             run du -s over the results, producing bytes
awk '...'                 get the first token of every line and add them up,
                          dividing by 1024 twice to produce MB
```

Comment: should be `cat /tmp/tmp.txt`

Comment: What if one wanted to exclude certain directories (in my case `/home/user` and `/media`?

Comment: Please specify du -b (binary size) to avoid wrong size reporting.
default du report the size in BLOCK (which can be 512 or 1024 ecc)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the flag `-L`:

From the man page:

```
-L, --dereference
              dereference all symbolic links
```

Then du calculates the size no matter whether they are symbolic or not.

Comment: This would not stop the `*` glob used on the command line from matching symbolic links.

Comment: Although I don't think this answers the question, it is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
du -P
```

-P, --no-dereference
don't follow any symbolic links (this is the default)