# Find file and directory size while ignoring symlink in sub-directories

Tags: shell, symlink, disk-usage

I have a directory structure where there are multiple symlinks at random depths.

For illustration purpose:

```
/fs
/fs/afile
/fs/blink -> /usr/local/lib
/fs/cdir/cfile
/fs/cdir/cdir/cdir/clink -> /var/log
/fs/edir/edir/efile
/fs/edir/elink -> /usr/local/bin
```

I want to find which file or folder utilizes the most space to do some cleanup. I am hoping an output similar to:

```
3.0G     /fs
4.0G     /fs/afile
3.3G     /fs/cdir
15.0G    /fs/edir
```

I tried running `cd /fs && find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sudo xargs du -hs` but this expands the symlinks underneath, which means the size of `/fs/edir` would include the content and size of `/usr/local/bin` in this case.

**TLDR:** For a given path, how do I find the size of all files or directories at `depth=1`, without expanding any underneath symlinks?

**Note:** I read [du skip symbolic links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157112/du-skip-symbolic-links) but this case is different as the symlink in this case could be of any depth.

Comment: Is your `du` an alias? The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) mandates `du` not to follow symlinks by default, anywhere in the file hierarchy. And neither does the GNU `du` I'm testing with.

Comment: Interesting, I thought symlinks were expanded because the size I get from du is larger than the df total disk space. Maybe I am missing something else here...

Comment: Then you should look for mount points. If some other device is mounted under `/fs`, then `du` will include it in its results unless you use its `-x` (skip directories on different file systems) option.